# Escalation timeout power automate

Tags: power-automate

I would like to repeat that scenario https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4iuVi1Vtgg&t=321s

But in my flow (below) on second condition flow end.

[image]
Error:

[image]

Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition' in line '1' and column '57970': 'Template language function endsWith' expects the type of the first parameter to be a string. The type of value provided is "Null". For details on use, please visit https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#endswith. ”.

Comment: Looks like you are passing null value to 2nd condition in your formula. check if variable has a value in it.

Comment: Yes, 2nd condition formula store Answer (First approval) = true, but first approval includes  timeout parametr - and this problem, how implement timeout escalation in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to handle these kinds of escalations is to:

- Create a new "**Scope**".
- Run this scope on a condition of "Failure".
- Place all your escalation activities insidde this scope.
- Terminate the flow with success inside your scope

[image]

This way you will be sure that you don't encounter the `null reference exception`.

Comment: Working in 50% :) Still I`ve got null in first approve. Second approve works.

Answer (score 1):

Some modification:
[image]

First approve - not working
Second aprrove - working.